# Dudley's integral convergence for stationary gaussian process

Tags: probability-theory, correlation

I am now studying "Gaussian processes" course at my university and i've faced a difficult problem for me:
Imagine we have a Gaussian stationary process with expectation equal to zero, variance equal to $1$, correlation function of this process is monotonic in the right neighbourhood of zero and it looks like: $r(t) = 1 - |t|^\delta\cdot(1 + o(1))$, $\delta > 0$, $t \rightarrow 0$. The question is: does the Dudley's integral of this process converge?
I have tried to build a Delone set for $(-\infty, \infty)$ using metric which is generated by this correlation function and after that my assumption is that this integral diverges, but i am really not sure if it is right.

Comment: 1) It would be better to add relevant definitions as well as your computations. 2) The theory makes little sense for an unbounded set, since the metric capacity will be infinite for every $\varepsilon>0$.